# ImageView doesn't fit with my linearlayout height

Tags: android, imageview, android-linearlayout, android-layout-weight

I got 5 imageview (layout_weight=2 each) in my linearLayout (weightSum=10)
All imageview have 0dp width, and wrap_content height, but I always have a top and bot margin...
When I use design view, if I try to manually adapt my linearlayout height (by extending the border) , this last is put to a fix value and this is not why I want (no more dynamic)

[image]

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/fond">

    <TextView/>

    <LinearLayout>

        <ImageView/>

        <TextView/>

        <TextView/>

        <ImageView/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:text="ECRANS DISPONIBLES"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selectsite_picto_search"
        android:drawablePadding="2dip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeScreenAvailableTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#26FFFFFF"
        android:weightSum="10">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_home_screen1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_poster1"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_home_screen2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_poster2"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_home_screen3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_poster3"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_home_screen4"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_poster4"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_home_screen5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/home_poster5"
            android:layout_weight="2"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView/>

    <TextView/>

    <TextView/>

    <TextView/>
</LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: see my answer @gamerounet..!!

Answer (score 2):

I finally find the solution to 
**android:scaleType="fitCenter"** and 
**android:adjustViewBounds="true"** in every imageView, and put layout_height="wrap_content" to the linearLayout

```
    <TextView
        android:text="ECRANS DISPONIBLES"
        android:drawableLeft="@drawable/selectsite_picto_near"
        android:drawablePadding="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:id="@+id/homeScreenAvailableTextView"
        android:textColor="#FFF" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#26FFFFFF"
        android:weightSum="10">
```

- ```
      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/item_home_screen2"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/home_poster2"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/item_home_screen3"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/home_poster3"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/item_home_screen4"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/home_poster4"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:scaleType="fitCenter"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

      <ImageView
          android:id="@+id/item_home_screen5"
          android:layout_width="0dp"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:src="@drawable/home_poster5"
          android:layout_weight="2"
          android:scaleType="fitStart"
          android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

  </LinearLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#26FFFFFF"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_home_screen1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="#AAAAAA"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_home_screen2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="#BBBB00"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_home_screen3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="#CC00CC"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_home_screen4"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="#DDBDDD"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_home_screen5"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="#00DDDD"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

//try this

Comment: No change, still same result. You only modify wrap_content by match_parent ?

Answer (score 0):

Please give `android:scaleType="fitXY"` for all the imageviews. This will set the height of the imageview as same as the height of the linear layout.

Comment: indeed the height of the IV is the same as the linearlayout, but my image are deformed/streched